# Mostrar dados do localstorage

Tags: javascript, localstorage

Criei um código que armazena os dados no localstorage, mas agora preciso que esses dados que estão no localstorage apareça na tela. Então quero saber como posso fazer isso. (Obs: estou desenvolvendo um formulário)

(html)

```
<button id=""cadastro" onclick="cadastro">Cadastrar</button>
```

(js)

```
window.onload = function (){
  document.querySelector("#cadastro").addEventListener("click",cadastrar)
}

function cadastrar(){
localStorage.setItem(nomeTabela.value, nomePropriedade.value);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para recuperar o valor do `localStorage` você usa a sintaxe:

```
localStorage.getItem("nome_do_localstorage");
```

Como você deu um nome a partir de um variável, ou você pode chamar pelo nome que deu ou pela própria variável:

```
localStorage.getItem(nomeTabela.value);
```

Você pode jogar o valor dentro de uma `div`:

```
<div id="minhadiv"></div>

<script>
document.body.querySelector("#minhadiv").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem(nomeTabela.value);
</script>
```

Juntando tudo na função, pode fazer assim:

```
<div id="minhadiv"></div>

<script>
function cadastrar(){
    localStorage.setItem(nomeTabela.value, nomePropriedade.value);
    var localsto = localStorage.getItem(nomeTabela.value);
    document.body.querySelector("#minhadiv").innerHTML = localsto;
}
</script>
```